# How to restrict wordpress search to pages and disable products listing search?

Tags: search, post-type

I have a requirement where i need to restrict wordpress search to pages listing only and disable products listing . In other words i wanted to replace post type in the search url from 'products' to 'page'. Any possible solution ?

Comment: It was solved as i uninstalled woo commerce plugin.

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways, but one easy way to achieve this if you wanted to customise the search results is to edit the search.php template and make the WP_Query a custom one:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    's' => get_search_query(),
    'post_type' => array('page'),
);

$search_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( have_posts() ) :

    while ( $search_query->have_posts() ) : $search_query->the_post();
        // do stuff here
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();

endif;
?>
```